# Using Custom Kafka State Stores in kstreams application

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

We are using Kafka-streams included within the spring cloud stream Hoxton RC7 project (and therefore use the Kafka-streams and Kafka-client versions provided [2.3.1])

```
ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', 'Hoxton.SR7')
}
...

dependencies {
    // spring cloud stream
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka'
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream")
    // redis 
    implementation 'io.lettuce:lettuce-core'
    implementation 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-redis'
    testCompile 'it.ozimov:embedded-redis:0.7.2'
    ...
```

We have implemented a kstreams application

```
@Bean
public Consumer<KStream<String, IncomingEvent>> process() {

    return input -> {
```

Where we do some aggregation within like:

```
.aggregate(Foo::new, (key, value1, aggregate) ->
                (aggregate == null || aggregate.getLastModified() == null || this.mustProcess(key, value1))
                        ? value1
                        : aggregate,
        materialized

)
```

Now materialized should be a custom external state store (Redis):

```
Materialized<String, Foo, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>> materialized =
        Materialized.as("redis-store");
```

Which is provided by a StoreBuilder Bean:

```
@Bean
public StoreBuilder<KeyValueStore<String, Foo>> builder(RedisKeyValueStoreBytes redisKeyValueStoreBytes){
    return Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(supplier(redisKeyValueStoreBytes),
            new Serdes.StringSerde(),
            new SomeFooSerde());
}


public static KeyValueBytesStoreSupplier supplier(RedisKeyValueStoreBytes redisKeyValueStoreBytes) {

    return new KeyValueBytesStoreSupplier() {
        @Override
        public String name() {
            return "redis-store";
        }

        @Override
        public KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]> get() {
            return redisKeyValueStoreBytes;
        }

        @Override
        public String metricsScope() {
            return "redis-session-state";
        }
    };
}
```

I now test the application with an EmbeddedKafka:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {TestConfigurationTests.class})
@EmbeddedKafka(count = 3, ports = {29901, 29902, 29903}, zookeeperPort = 33991)
public class TestKafkaIntegration {
```

Where I try to access the state store and query the items added:

```
ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<String, Foo> queryableStore = interactiveQueryService.getQueryableStore(
        "redis-store", QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore());
return queryableStore;
```

But when I run my test I receive an error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Could not start stream: ; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Could not start stream: ; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.TopologyException: Invalid topology: StateStore redis-store is already added.
```

Several questions:

- The examples for using custom state stores explained by [1] use it within a Processor. Does this automatically mean, I am not able to use a custom state store in an aggregation?
- When it is not possible to use it within an aggregation, what is the point of using custom state stores anyway?
- When I slightly change the code above for the kstreams and define a processor instead of using materialized in the aggregate method, the error changes, it then complains about a missing state "redis-store" store while trying to execute getQueryableStore. But indeed i can see, that the addStateStoreBeans registers the 'redis-store'. How can this happen?

The reason why I want to use a custom state store is, that I am not (really easily) able to have a dedicated hard disk for the application instance. To have a fast startup for the application I want to avoid processing of the complete changelog on each startup of the application (which should preferably take place several times a day and currently takes more than an hour). So now the last question:

- When a custom external state store is used, am I able to resume to the last state on application restart?

[1] https://spring.io/blog/2019/12/09/stream-processing-with-spring-cloud-stream-and-apache-kafka-streams-part-6-state-stores-and-interactive-queries

Answer (score 1):

You are using [Materialized.as(java.lang.String storeName)](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.kafka/kafka-streams/latest/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/Materialized.html) which will create (materialize) a `StateStore` with the given name ("redis-store" here). On the other hand,  with `builder(RedisKeyValueStoreBytes redisKeyValueStoreBytes)` you are creating *another* `StateStore` having the same name, which springframework is probably automatically adding it to the topology, such that you get "store is already added" error.

q1: you can use a custom state store in an aggregation; use it with [Materialized.as(KeyValueBytesStoreSupplier supplier)](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.kafka/kafka-streams/latest/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/Materialized.html)

q2: one could also use a `StateStore` with a transformer or a custom processor for interactive queries; also with a *global* `StateStore` one could access the entire topic instead of [KafkaStreams](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.kafka/kafka-streams/latest/org/apache/kafka/streams/KafkaStreams.html) instance only allocated partitions (see [addGlobalStore](https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.kafka/kafka-streams/2.6.0/org/apache/kafka/streams/StreamsBuilder.html#addGlobalStore-org.apache.kafka.streams.state.StoreBuilder-java.lang.String-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Consumed-org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.ProcessorSupplier-) and [globalTable](https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.kafka/kafka-streams/2.6.0/org/apache/kafka/streams/StreamsBuilder.html#globalTable-java.lang.String-))

q3: I guess you didn't (manually) register the state store with the topology; see [Topology.addStateStore(StoreBuilder<?> storeBuilder, java.lang.String... processorNames)](https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.kafka/kafka-streams/2.6.0/org/apache/kafka/streams/Topology.html#addStateStore-org.apache.kafka.streams.state.StoreBuilder-java.lang.String...-) and [Connecting Processors and State Stores](https://kafka.apache.org/26/documentation/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html#connecting-processors-and-state-stores)

q4: yes, the state store [is loaded from a changelog topic](https://kafka.apache.org/26/documentation/streams/architecture#streams_architecture_recovery) (could be the original topic when using [optimizations](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/optimizing-streams.html#optimization-details))